# position responsive fixed button to div container css

Tags: html, css

I want to position a button responsively at the right bottom corner. So far I have put the button fixed to the centered container.

**The Problem**

If at any time I stretch the page (up and down , or side ways up and down) it disappears/looses focus for a slight second.

**Expected:**

I would like this yellow button to be vissible at all times, even if the browser is stretched.

**Code:**

```css
    .container{
     margin:0 auto;
     max-width:480px;
     height: 50vh;
     width: 100%;
     text-align:center;
     background:blue;
      }
    .fixed_button{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 20px;/*height: auto;*/
    margin-left: 405px;
    border: 0px solid #d6d6d6;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow; 
     }
     .spaces{
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
     }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="spaces"></div>
  <div class="spaces"></div>
  <div class="spaces"></div>
  <div class="spaces"></div>
  <div class="spaces"></div>
        <div class="fixed_button"></div>
 </div>
```

Also if you want to see the visibility effect, just open snippet , click `full page` and stretch your window around.

Container:blue & fixed button:yellow.

[image: yellow button responsive fixed to container]

by the way, the container has a croll to load plugin, so it grows downwards anytime the user scrolls down the page, so `.container` growns and the button cant be positioned absolutely.

Comment: use percentage values instead of pixels.  use `bottom:2%` or something instead of `bottom:10px`

Comment: My problem is the right positioning,I tried with `margin-left:x%;` but at the moment I stretch the page the button moves to the center

Comment: So is the button supposed to be fixed to the window...or the container?

Comment: don't use `margin-left`, just use `left` with some percentage value, or `right` with some percentage values

Comment: looks like you are looking alignment based on the container, not for window. In that case, go with absolute position element and apply bottom, right values.

Comment: the absolute position doesnt work for me, because the conainer  `.container` grows anytime it is scrolled downwards. the absolute position doesnt work at all, because the container grows and grows..

Comment: initially if the container have too much height, user need to see the yellow button. so if user scrolls also you want the yellow should stay in the same place. looks like you want to fix it to window bottom, but it is relative to the container width.

Comment: yes. you got it. this is my problem, and my questiond doesnt deserve an down vote.Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: This question deserves up-votes! As i understand everything works but asoon as th OP stretches his browser up & down the div moves out of focus and then back .. would like to know  a fix as well.

Comment: @joe given my answer. check it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can align a button at the bottom of a div by using position absolute. You can try changing your css to this.

```
    .fixed_button{ 
     position: absolute; 
     bottom: 5px;
     right: 5px;
     width: 70px; 
     border: 0px solid #d6d6d6;  
     //wrest of your styles 
     }
```

This should have the behaviour your looking for. Hope this helps

Comment: my page contains an scroll to load plugin, so the container `.container` grows anytime it is scrolled downwards. the absolute position doesnt work at all, because the container grows and grows..

Comment: Thats odd. You say it displaces to the right of the page even with position fixed? I am just wondering if your margin-left: 405px does that. Suppose I never used a scroll to load plugin.

Comment: the scroll to load plugin only avoid using absolute positioning to `.container`, the displacement to the right is because the button is not responsive to the container with that `margin left`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button fixed at the lower right bottom, you can use
 position: absolute instead of fixed.

If you want responsive design, then don't use margin property with PX value. try to use with the percentage (%)

Try the following code snippet,

```
.fixed_button{
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
right: 10px;
width: 70px;
height: auto;
padding: 25px;
border: none;
z-index: 99;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
-moz-transition: all .25s ease;
-ms-transition: all .25s ease;
-o-transition: all .25s ease;
transition: all .25s ease;
text-align: center;
 }
```

I hope this will help,

Comment: It dissapear after scrolling down.

Comment: Okay, if your container height is dynamic then try to use position: sticky or relative.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, pure CSS solution won't work. You have to use `Jquery` to calculate the width of the container after window resize and then calculate the right position then assign it to your fixed element.

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){
   var conwidth = $('.container').width()/2 - 30;
   $('.fixed_button').css('left','calc(50% + '+conwidth+'px)');
});
```

```css
.container{
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:480px;
 height:600px;
 text-align:center;
 background:blue;
  }
.fixed_button{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: calc(50% + 210px);
width: 30px;
border-radius:50%;
height:30px;
z-index: 99;
background: yellow; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed_button"></div>
</div>
```

So I did the calculation like get the container width and then divide it by two then minus the fixed element width. After that I applied it as left position for the fixed element.

Here is the [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/z6va8d4e/20/) you can play with it.

Comment: His problem is if you stretch the window/browser when viewing your snippet full page, the yellow div looses visibility, he does not want that to happen?

Comment: it is visible...check it my fiddle now.

Comment: your solution looks quite interesting, I'm going to try it out. thank you.

Comment: i see , so far the best solution, but its still not 100%, if i resize quickly up it kind of loses visibility but best solution i would say.

Comment: I think it would need a transtion to work 100% perfect. but its currently quite good! this is the solution to my question!!

Comment: Well, after testing it for several times, this code doesn work if we start from the stretched position, if the container is already stretched, I think the css code `calc()` doesnt make a good calculation is the calculation starts with the container already stretched as in a mobile form...

Comment: so find the solution from your end and post here. let see what you got.